# How to turn CSV file into list of rows?

Tags: python, macos, csv

I currently have a CSV file saved as Windows comma separated values

```
f = open('file.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in lines:
    print row
```

returns

```
Company,City,State

Ciena Corporation,Linthicum,Maryland

Inspirage LLC,Gilbert,Arizona

Facebook,menlo park,CA
```

I am trying to make a list column by column

```
f = open('file.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in f:
    print row[2]
f.close()
```

and am receiving just the 3rd letter: `m`, `e`, `s` and `c`.

Writing in Python on Mac

Comment: Can you clarify the question by adding the expected output?

Comment: You need to iterate over `csv_f` instead of the open file.

Comment: To your claim that the first code block returns some stuff - how can it return anything - where is `lines` defined? It throws a NameError.

Answer (score 1):

As a proper way for dealing with `csv` files you can use `csv` module :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('f_name.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print baseUrl + ' '.join(row)
```

This will give your rows as a list. and if you want all of them in a list just do :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('f_name.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     print list(spamreader)
```

Note that `spamreader` is an iterator and you can convert it to list by `list()` function.

you can also get the list of columns by passing `spamreader` to `zip` function :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('f_name.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     print zip(*spamreader)
```

Comment: thank you! I am trying to attach each part of the list to a bing search. For example baseUrl = "https://www.bing.com". I want the program to iterate through and for reach row run baseUrl + "company" + "city" + "state" How would I do that?

Comment: @al_coast2 In that case you can join `row` checkout the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This function reads CSV and returns it as a list

```
def csv2list(csvFile):
    outList = list()
    reader = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
    for row in reader:
        outList.append(row)            
    return outList
```

Usage example :

```
csv_file = "somthing.csv"
print csv2list(csv_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `for row in csv_f: …`, not `for row in f: …`.